# Checkbox and label created on the fly

Tags: jquery, dom, appearance, on-the-fly

When I create a checkbox and a label "on the fly" with jQuery, it works fine respect to its functionality (that is: if I click the label, the checkbox is checked), but the default visual appearance that the browser assigns to the label isn't the same as the default visual appearance assigned for a label created not-on-the-fly.

```
[x] normal label
[x]label created on the fly
```

The difference is a space (a margin) between the label and the check box.

**Any ideas on what is happening here?**

The code for the checkbox/label creation on the fly is the following:

```
 $('<input type="checkbox" id="foo"/><label for="foo">bar</label>')
```

The code for the checkbox/label creation not-on-the-fly is the following:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="baz"/><label for="baz">quz</label>
```

Comment: Try making a live demo when posting that kind of question. This is non-repro with your [given code](http://jsfiddle.net/W4y6t/).

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a space between the input and the label? Also use the inspector to see if there is any css that might be affecting the elements.

Comment: Inspect you html element with your browsers developer tools to see what is happening, check the element contents and applied styles

Comment: Agh, sorry guys. There was a space in the not-on-the-fly render. But in the code there isn't. The <label> tag is one line after the <input> tag. That line is interpreted as a space? This is what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/kSjJZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what was happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/kSjJZ/

```
 <body>
     <ul id="bla">
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" id="baz"/><label for="baz">quz</label>
         </li>
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" id="foo"/>
             <label for="foo">quz</label>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </body>
```

Basically, theres a space interpretation if these two tags (input and label) are separated by a \r\n

Comment: so you found your answer, i guess.